# ASP.Net 2.0 Reference and manipulate a Checkbox control during postback

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a checkbox control that's populated based on the validity of initial input values during form submission.  Basically it works as follows:

Initial page is rendered with texbox fields and a hidden Checkbox List control

-->The input from the text boxes are validated during postback and if they are good, the checkbox list is populated with other values and presented to the user.

I've tried searching for the checkboxlist control during post back in order to dynamically populate, but that approach didn't get me anywhere.  Is it possible to find the checkbox list control and dynamically populate it during postback?

Comment: Show us your approach to find the checkboxlist that would make it easier find your problem. Also you should show us the aspx markup.

Comment: You should just have a reference to the control in the code behind, or is it a pure HTML checkbox? In which case you can grab the data out of the form post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are checking the posted form values, you won't find your control there as it is restored from viewstate (if its not a dynamic control that is).

Is your checkboxlist dynamic or an actual control on the page you can see in your designer?
What are you searching on postback? Are you using FindControl?

Use FindControl to search for it. If it doesn't exist then on postback then in Page_Init you'll want to dynamically create it again (only if it was a dynamic control to begin with)

Comment: Hi Adam, sorry I left that critical detail out.  The checkbox list is a dynamic control.  I've been doing some reading and have realized I can't search for that control and must readd it during Page_Init.  Thanks for the suggestion.  I'm reworking my implementation.